# Firefox event.clientX not functioning

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, dom-events

I'm working on a d3 and js project.

The beginning of the function looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    d3.select("#aid").select(".abutton").on("mousemove",function() {
        afile.style("top", (event.clientY+10)+"px").style("left",(event.clientX+15)+"px");
        afile.html("<h3>Click text here</p><p>or here</p>");
    });
```

I've done quite a bit of Googling!

The essence is that on [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/), it should do the function. This works in Chrome and IE because the event variable is global, and as such so are it's client* properties.

The solution, as I understand it, is to pass in an `eventObject`. When I do that, my code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    d3.select("#aid").select(".abutton").on("mousemove",function(event) {
        afile.style("top", (event.clientY+10)+"px").style("left",(event.clientX+15)+"px");
        afile.html("<h3>Click text here</p><p>or here</p>");
    });
```

The Firefox log gives me:

> [09:59:04.308] TypeError: event is undefined @ filepathofjavascriptfile

and similarly, it breaks in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientY' of undefined filepathofjavascriptfile
>   (anonymous function) help.js:34

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I think d3 does things differently than jQuery; the event object is stored globally as a property of the d3 object I think. (I don't know much about d3 but I just saw a talk about it the other day.) I think that it's `d3.event` in fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
d3.select("#aid").select(".abutton").on("mousemove",function() {
    afile.style("top", (d3.event.clientY+10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.clientX+15)+"px");
    afile.html("<h3>Click text here</p><p>or here</p>");
});
```

For whatever reason, that's how d3 exposes the event object.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Did not realize you had to use d3's event listener, but that makes more sense now.

Comment: Just search the documentation: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_event